# Proof by Induction with different Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$SA=AT$, where $S$ and $T$ have no eigenvalues in common. Prove by induction that $(T-\lambda I)^kv=0$ implies that $Av=0$.

Here is what I have so far:

$k=1$: $$
(T-\lambda I)v=0
$$$$
Tv=\lambda v
$$$$
SAv=ATv=\lambda Av
$$$$
SAv=\lambda Av
$$ $Av$ must equal $0$ because $S$ and $T$ share no eigenvectors.

$k=n$: $$
(T-\lambda I)^nv=0  \textrm{ implies } Av=0
$$

$k=n+1$: now what?

Comment: for $k=n$ you should have $Av = 0$, for what it's worth.

Comment: @SamuelYusim thanks lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the $k=n+1$ case into:
$$
0 = (T-\lambda I)^{n+1} v = (T - \lambda I)^n (T - \lambda I) v := (T - \lambda I)^n w
$$
where $w = (T- \lambda I)v$. Now use the inductive step to conclude that $Aw = 0$.

This implies that
$$
A(T - \lambda I)v = 0 \\
ATv = \lambda A v \\
S(Av) = \lambda (Av)
$$
Hence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $S$. But we know that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, and so $Av = 0$.